# Configure ssl certificate for owncloud

Tags: server, apache2, ssl, https, owncloud-server

I am bit confused with here with SSL certificate installation for own cloud.

```
Setup 

OS  : Ubuntu 18.04

APP : OWN Cloud

Certificate : I have already certificate from Public CA ( comodo ).
```

we are already running emails and FTP services with this certificate. it is wildcard certificate.

I have installed own cloud server for file transfer and storage and have need to configure the SSL certificate.

can someone please help me here.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Owncloud server documentation (for the latest stable release 10.2), it is needed to enable the feature, by adding this line to the config.php file:

```
'enable_certificate_management' => true,
```

More details can be found [here](https://doc.owncloud.com/server/10.2/admin_manual/configuration/server/import_ssl_cert.html).

Comment: I have successfully imported the certificate and there is still information missing how to force own cloud to use this certificate and only works with HTTPS